# PHP - Reading multiline CSV

Tags: php, sql, database, csv, fgetcsv

I've had no issue with the first line of a CSV being read upon upload and then inserted into the database, but the multi line task is having issues. I can now get it to print an array dump on the web page that shows all lines of the CSV but it's still only inserting the first line into my database. I've worked my code around and came up with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

 while(!feof($handle)){
$filesop = print_r(fgetcsv($handle, 0, ","));
 }
$coldata = array();
```

I have this code for calling the queries (there are other queries after this, but this is the main one that puts into that staging table):

```
 $tablenames = array("staging"/*,"clients","meters","tests","costs","workorders"*/);

for($tableno = 0;$tableno < sizeof($tablenames);$tableno++){
$q = "";
$q2 = "";
$q3 = "";
$q4 = "";
$q5 = "";
$q6 = "";
$col_list = '`'.str_replace(',','`,`',$table_cols[$tableno]).'`';
$q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$col_list.") VALUES (";
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
$cols = explode(",",$table_cols[$tableno]);
$data = array();
foreach($cols as $key => $fldname) {
    $data[] = "'".$coldata[$fldname]."'";
}

/*INSERT INTO STAGING TABLE - INITAL CSV UPLOAD*/
$q .= implode(",",$data).");";
```

Am I doing something wrong in the queries that's causing it to not insert all lines of the CSV into the db?

Comment: When I run into problems like this I like to echo or log as much as I can to see where things go wrong, usually you find that the code is doing something you don't expect it to. So maybe echo each query you are building to make sure it looks the way it should?

Comment: sizeof($tablenames) is 1. So the for loop is executing once and doing 1 insert.

Comment: Yes, I definitely dumped everything on the success page so I get a successful connection message, then the arrays for all lines in the CSV print, then it prints all 6 of my queries which show properly, and last it shows my success message for file insertion. But now when I upload, nothing is inserted, I get a new primary key but a blank line in my staging table. IF I remove the while loop around my fgetcsv call, it inserts properly again, but it's only the first line

Comment: @Arun, I have the for loop starting at 0 but if some CSV files will be 6 lines and some will be 12, how would I instantiate the number of times it runs? I have the handle reading until eof

Comment: @H.Norman why not read the file line by line and insert the record to db? Something like 
`while(!feof($handle))
{
   //Read Line from CSV
   //Insert Line to DB
}`

Comment: Well, this project has already been established but basically this PHP file has a column array with 200 elements (each with the variable name that matches the SQL table) that need to be inserted into the staging table and are then called on later to display the information in certain tables. So everything is read and inserted in a particular way, I just need it to read the 200 fields, then line break and read the next 200, etc. That's where I'm having some issues